# Getting Array positions in HTML automatically

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have many arrays some upto 60 some upto 100. I am trying to get the text at the 0 position of this arrays for all arrays. I am sorry I don't know how to frame the question correctly. I don't want to type (greeting[0])[1] etc for say 100 times for every greeting. This is my code so far. Can someone help me in this! The greeting[0] etc actually go till 60 etc. Is it possible to do something like let i = 0 , for greeting.length , if i < greeting.length , i++ , and somehow put (greeting[i][0]}. And the result will be such that it show the values of all greeting shows in the paragraph element or in a separate window or something. I am still new to HTML so forgive me is if this seems basic.

Edited Question Update.
P.S. Some of my Arrays have the format greeting[0] = new Greet["Hola", "Salve", "Olá"] . I had to do it such because I use the three options. Is there any way I can automate the process with this?

Edited Question - Update 1
So I have updated the code to be more representative of what I am trying to ask. Basically here I want to provide a button so that on clicking the button I can see all the English words I can choose from. So I want to do something like get the value of the English words in greeting 0, 1 etc and display them separately so that we can select which English word we want instead of just numbers which we don't know what word they represent. Can someone help me with this please!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="English"> Select English Word </p>

    <p id="French"> Click below button </p>

    <p id="Italian"> Click below button </p>

    <button onclick="Another()"> CLick </button>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
var greeting = [];
greeting[0] = new Word("Hi", "salut", "Ciao") ;
greeting[1] = new Word("Hello", "Salve", "Ciao") ;
greeting[2] = new Word("Welcome", "Bienvenue", "benvenuta") ;
greeting[3] = new Word("Good Day", "Bonne journée", "Buona giornata") ;
greeting[4] = new Word("Good Day", "Bonjour", "Buongiorno") ;



function Word(English,French,Italian) {
    this.English = English ;
    this.French = French ;
    this.Italian = Italian ;
} ;


function Another() {

var nums = window.prompt("Select a number within " + greeting.length ) ;

var optionuser = greeting[nums] ;

var selection = alert("You selected English word " + optionuser.English )


document.getElementById("English").innerHTML = optionuser.English ;
document.getElementById("French").innerHTML = optionuser.French ;
document.getElementById("Italian").innerHTML = optionuser.Italian ;
}
```

Comment: You could follow your own process and instead push the elements you find into a new array and just `console.log` the new array.

Comment: Yes! I tried that. But was unsuccessful. I am still in the learning process in javascript. So I quite dont know how to achieve what I want yet!

Comment: How was it unsuccessful?

Comment: @Rojo Simply put I dont know how to do that  . I know the very basics of basics. Its all self taught using online tutorials at tutorialspoint w3schools etc. So I did try, but some error always came.

Comment: Whenever you get an error, literally copy and paste the error into google! That's how I learned. I also am (still) learning online. You could also show me the errors and I could probably translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `Array.map(callback)` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = greeting.map(item=>item[0]).join("<br>");
```

Comment: ! Thanks a lot! That solves it. But some of my arrays have this format. greetings = new Greets ["Hola", "Salve", "Olá"] . And it does not work for them. Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: `new Greets` creates an instance of the class `Greets`. Please show where you define that class. See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: That was a useful article. Thanks. I have updated the code to be more representative of what i am asking. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @KarthiDiamond97 I think you are searching for the `<select>` element. (See: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)). I took your code and trasformed it to make this fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/Etibi/0xr5u21L/](https://jsfiddle.net/Etibi/0xr5u21L/)

Answer (score 0):

I have given a slightly modified code below.Hope this is what you are looking for. Since you are new, one advise is not to use window.prompt in your code. Explore some other way. Also change the `function Word` to `Class Word`. I think you were trying to create a Class but have given wrong keyword. Instead of prompt, I have used radio button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Select Language:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="English" name="language" value="English">
    <label for="English">English</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="French" name="language" value="French">
    <label for="French">French</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="Italian" name="language" value="Italian">
    <label for="Italian">Italian</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="Spanish" name="language" value="Spanish">
    <label for="Spanish">Spanish</label><br>
    <button onclick="Another()">Click</button>
    <p id="msg"></p>
<script>
class Word {
    constructor(English,French,Italian){
    this.English = English ;
    this.French = French ;
    this.Italian = Italian ;
    }
} ;
var greeting = [];
greeting[0] = new Word("Hi", "salut", "Ciao") ;
greeting[1] = new Word("Hello", "Salve", "Ciao") ;
greeting[2] = new Word("Welcome", "Bienvenue", "benvenuta") ;
greeting[3] = new Word("Good Day", "Bonne journée", "Buona giornata") ;



function Another() {

let optionSelected = document.querySelector('input[name="language"]:checked').value; 
document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += 'You selected:'+optionSelected;
for(let i=0;i<greeting.length;i++){
document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += '<br>' + greeting[i][optionSelected];    
}
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: Use separate .js file as you did. For answering purpose i have used inline style.

Comment: Thanks! But some of my arrays have this format. greetings = new Greets ["Hola", "Salve", "Olá"] . And it does not work for them. Is there any way to make them work in this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you talking about greeting instantiated like this greeting[2] = new Array("Hola", "Salve", "Olá") using array keyword. What is the Greets you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes! I have updated the code to show my point more clearly. Please have a look at it and let me know how to go about it.